# Java Classloader default classloader

Tags: java, classloader, java-6

please tell me which JDK class by default  is used to load application class
into jvm.It can't be Classloader class since its abstract class.so which JDK class is used to load application class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experimentation on Oracle OpenJDK 8, this is [`sun.misc.Lanucher$AppClassLoader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/Launcher.java#Launcher.AppClassLoader) which subclasses the concrete (non-abstract) [`URLClassLoader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/URLClassLoader.java).

<sub>The links given are to the JDK6 source as per the tags in the original question. The Java 8 AppClassLoader is available [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/misc/Launcher.java#Launcher.AppClassLoader).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

When you read the theory then usually the first classloader is called a bootstrap class loader. The instance will differ based on implementation (HotSpot, JRockit, IBM and based on version). There is more information on this at the [Java API Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).